# Failing to Open File from User Input

Tags: c++, file

I have tried to open a file in C++ from user input, using the relative name in the same directory as the source code. However, it keeps failing for me and I can't figure out why.

Edit: I forgot C++ uses double backslash to read Paths, Fully Qualified File Name Works! I still need relative location to work though :/

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool openFileIn(fstream& file, string name)
{
    file.open(name, ios::in); 

    if (file.fail())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    fstream inFile;
    string fileName;

    // Get filename from user
    cout << "Please input the stock data file name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    // Open and check for errors
    if (!openFileIn(inFile, fileName))
    {
        cerr << "Error opening file for input!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: I suppose that  you have to place the file to be opened in the directory where the compiler generates the executables; you placed it in the directory where the source files reside, correct?

Comment: Your code is good. The problem are the files (check their rights?) or the filenames you provided, make sure you don't forget the extensions.

Comment: As far as style notes, you should just `return !file.fail()` and stop writing `using namespace std;`. Your code looks fine though, like the others have said, as long as you understand what your working directory is and how to use relative paths from there.

Comment: To elaborate on @StephanLechner's remark, you could use some functions from boost::filesysrem to assess what is the absolute path of the file you are trying to open. You could for example use boost::filesystem::current_path() to retrieve the current path, or directly use boost::filesystem::absolute to get the absolute path from your relative path.
See for example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path or https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#absolute and